# Python Restarting a loop

Tags: python, loops, operators

How can I restart the loop in the following code after it hits 1 since in 3N+1 it goes 1>4>2>1?

Code:

```
import math
import random
num = 1
NumTF = False
play = True
while play:
  if num % 2 == 0:
    num = num / 2
  else:
    num = 3 * num + 1
print(num)
if num == 1:
  play = False
if play == False:
  num += 1 and play == True
```

Comment: beware of the last line, `num += 1 and play == True`, which may not do what you're thinking it might do

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to end the loop, because ...Collatz Conjecture.

All you have to do is add this simple if statement to the end:

```
elif num == 1:
    play = False
```

after the `if num%2 == 0` statement, so the while loop ends. Currently, your doing this after your doing `num = 3*num+1`, which makes it 4, so that case never happens. as rv.kvetch mentioned, the `play==True` does unexpected things, so just delete everything after `print(num)`, as those are unnecessary.